# Why doesn't IRB display output when executing in VS Code Terminal?

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code, irb

Newbie here.. I'm trying out VS Code and am running into an issue. I've connected VS Code to WSL through remote connection and everything is running great expect for IRB.. When I open IRB in the Terminal and execute a command, the output is not displayed. If I open pry and execute a command, output is displayed as normal. Even weirder, when using IRB if I switch to the Output tab and then back to Terminal all the output is displayed. Examples below:

```
➜  ~ irb
3.0.0 :001 > 1 + 1

3.0.0 :002 > greeting = 'hello'

3.0.0 :003 >
```

```
➜  ~ pry
[1] pry(main)> 1 + 1
=> 2
[2] pry(main)> greeting = 'hello'
=> "hello"
[3] pry(main)>
```

If I copy the lines where IRB output is displayed and paste on newline, the output is exactly as expected. Any help would be awesome!